# Using Jquery in UserControl with MasterPage

Tags: javascript, user-controls, textbox, master-pages, multiline

I can't seem to get Javascript to work on my usercontrol.  All I want to do is count the characters in a **mulitline textbox** (which adds another level of complexity).  I want to count the characters and display them in a label.

I have my javascript in a .js file included in the MasterPage:

```
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
    var output = document.getElementById(countfield);
    if (output == null) { return; }

    if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    else
        output.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

My UserControl has little code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    if (typeof contentPageLoad == 'function') {
        var outputField = $("[id$='lblCharacterCount']");
    }
</script> 


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTest" runat="server" Height="75px" CssClass="form-field full" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="140"
            onkeyup="textCounter(this, outputField, 140);" onkeydown="textCounter(this, outputField, 140);" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblCharacterCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**outputField** is always null when it tries to execute the function.  I've tried adding it(the script on the UserControl) in a scriptblock in the UserControl PageLoad, PreRender and PreInit. Nothing seems to work.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get UserControl Javascript working w/o an UpdatePanel.  That was the problem, the UserControl was in an UpdatePanel.  I've given up on using a Usercontrol in an updatepanel with JS unless someone can offer any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the selector to something like this:

```
var outputField = $("#<% lblCharacterCount.ClientId %>");
```

The ID you set on the control is usually not the ID that gets assigned to it in the HTML that is generated. Using the ClientId property, will get you that HTML ID.

Of course I haven't used ASP.NET in a while so this answer might be worthless.

Comment: Thanks Jason, your syntax was a little off but I had already tried that.  It still comes back 'undefined'.